# .htaccess mod_rewrite not working

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this code somewhere in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule /user/([a-zA-Z0-9]+) /iduser.php?username=$1
```

It *should* make `/user/oliolio` request `iduser.php?username=oliolio`, however it doesn't work.  :(

Do you know why?

Comment: Can you confirm that rewrite rules are working over all, too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/user/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /iduser.php?username=$2 [L]
```

Or if its just yourdomain.com/user/ollio
then

```
 RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /iduser.php?username=$1 [L]
```

Make sure `RewriteEngine On` is set

Comment: Appreciate that you kept the asker's character/number restriction in the regex, but might want to simplify to using [a-z0-9] and adding the "nocase / NC" directive

Answer (score 3):

Have your rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)/?$ /iduser.php?username=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Apache strips out leading slash `/` that's why your rule is not working.